# How to disable "pull to refresh" action and use only indicator?

Tags: android, material-design, pull-to-refresh, swiperefreshlayout

I enabled "pull to refresh" to my project using the `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

When I move down,  appear the loading indicator (material design style). I know, it must so work, but I want to disable this function, and start refreshing by click some button and use `SwipeRefreshLayout` loading indicator.

How I can to do this?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

From the documentation:

> If an activity wishes to show just the progress animation, it should call setRefreshing(true). To disable the gesture and progress animation, call setEnabled(false) on the view.

So to show the animation:

```
swiperefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
swiperefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

And to hide the animation:

```
swiperefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
swiperefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: you can `setEnabled(false)` just once, and then `setRefreshing(true or false)`

Answer (score 24):

You don't have to always enable and disable. Just disable once when the view is created and then use setRefreshing.