# Recylerview On Pull do some task

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pull-to-refresh, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to do some task NOT REFRESH when I am pulling a recyclerView, but the problem is it's showing the reload icon. I don't want to show that. I try to hide that in this way:

```
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(0,0,0,0);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // Refresh items
        }
    });
```

**But it still showing a round circle with shadow. How can I detect pulling in a recylerview using Swiperefreshlayout (with out progress icon) or any other way?**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)`.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30328196/2949612

Use of [void setRefreshing (boolean refreshing)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setRefreshing(boolean)) :

Whether or not the view should show refresh progress.

**Edits**:

As per [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) doc:

> If an activity wishes to show just the progress animation, it should call `setRefreshing(true)`. To **disable** the gesture and progress animation, call `setEnabled(false)` on the view.

So you also need to add `swiprefreshLayout.setEnabled( false );` after `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)` line.

Comment: Still refresh icon is shwing

Comment: Then how can I listne for that onRefresh()?

Comment: I want to to listnen for the funtion onRefresh() but don't want to show the refresh icon

Comment: After adding this 2 line I am not getting onRefresh() any more

Comment: Yes this is for disable refreshing.

Comment: You need to add `.setRefreshing(false)` line in `onRefresh` method .

Comment: I don't want to disable it I need to hide the refresh icon I still need the refresh functionality

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117519/discussion-between-pranay-and-bumba).

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need a line of code to do this

```
SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)
```